# File Logger for android apps

Tags: java, android, logging

I want the simplest logger there is to simply log errors, mostly exceptions, to a Log file in the android file system. for exemple, the easiest and most convinient (in my opinion at least) way that i used to log to a file on PC java was by simply printing all exceptions to console and redirecting system out to both console and my file, this doesnt really suffice on android as far as i know i guess its because of how Android OS is designed, so what is the simplest way of doing it in Android?

Note that the project has already lot of code in it and i really wouldnt like to go over it and add log calls on catch blocks or whatever to log my exceptions, as little i need to do for logging those exceptions is best for my use case...

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

It's not finished but works quite stable. It saves human readable json array with exception name, time, stack trace and additional data. Also you can save logcat's logs.

**Using**:

```
ExceptionWriter ew = new ExceptionWriter(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "debug.txt"));
ew.w(new IllegalArgumentException("some msg"), "additional message");
```

**Source**:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

/**
 * User: elevenetc
 * Date: 10/9/13
 * Time: 12:52 PM
 */
public class ExceptionWriter {

    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private final ExceptionWriter.WriteExceptionTask writeExceptionTask;
    private final SimpleDateFormat dataFormat;
    private int totalExceptions;
    private StringBuilder stackBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    public int getTotalExceptions(){return totalExceptions;}

    public ExceptionWriter(File file) throws IOException {
        if(file != null){
            writeExceptionTask = new WriteExceptionTask(file);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            dataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
            new Thread(writeExceptionTask).start();
        }else{
            sb = null;
            writeExceptionTask = null;
            dataFormat = null;
        }

    }

    public synchronized int wLogcat(){
        try {
            writeExceptionTask.addStreamToRead(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v time").getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public int w(Exception debugException, String caughtMessage){
        return w(debugException, caughtMessage, null);
    }

    public synchronized int w(Exception debugException, String caughtMessage, String additionalData){

        if(writeExceptionTask == null) return -1;

        sb.setLength(0);

        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = debugException == null ? null : debugException.getStackTrace();

        sb.append("{\"date\":\"");sb.append(getTime());
        sb.append("\",\"exceptionClassName\":\"");sb.append(debugException == null ? null : debugException.getClass());
        sb.append("\",\"exceptionMessage:\":\"");sb.append(debugException == null ? null : debugException.getMessage());
        sb.append("\",\"caughtMessage:\":\"");sb.append(caughtMessage);
        if(additionalData != null) {sb.append("\",\"data:\":\"");sb.append(additionalData);}
        sb.append("\",\"stack\":");sb.append(stackToString(stackTrace));
        sb.append("},");

        writeExceptionTask.stringQueue.add(sb.toString());

        totalExceptions++;

        return 0;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        if(writeExceptionTask != null) {
            writeExceptionTask.stop();
        }
    }

    private String getTime(){
        return dataFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    private String stackToString(StackTraceElement[] stackTrace){

        if(stackTrace == null) return null;

        stackBuilder.setLength(0);

        stackBuilder.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.length; i++) {
            StackTraceElement e = stackTrace[i];

            stackBuilder.append("{\"");
            stackBuilder.append(e.getLineNumber());
            stackBuilder.append("\":\"");
            stackBuilder.append(e.getClassName());
            stackBuilder.append(".");
            stackBuilder.append(e.getMethodName());
            stackBuilder.append("\"}");

            if(i != stackTrace.length -1) stackBuilder.append(",");
        }
        stackBuilder.append("]");
        return stackBuilder.toString();
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Static classes
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    private class WriteExceptionTask implements Runnable {

        private final File file;
        private boolean running;
        private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> stringQueue;
        private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<InputStream> isQueue;
        private final FileWriter writer;

        private WriteExceptionTask(File file) throws IOException {
            this.file = file;
            writer = new FileWriter(this.file, true);
            stringQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
            isQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<InputStream>();
            running = true;
        }

        public void addStreamToRead(InputStream is){
            if(is != null){
                isQueue.add(is);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running){
                if(!stringQueue.isEmpty()){

                    //TODO check file existence

                    try {
                        writer.append(stringQueue.poll());
                        writer.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        running = false;
                    }
                }

                if(!isQueue.isEmpty()){
                    InputStream is = isQueue.poll();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{\"catLog\":\"");

                    String aux;

                    try {

                        while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            //TODO view like array or \n
                            builder.append(aux);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    builder.append("\"},");

                    stringQueue.add(builder.toString());
                }
            }

            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void stop() {
            running = false;
        }
    }

}
```